# yahoo not opening with Tenda (TE-w308R) router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have Tenda N ADSL2+ router. I configured it correctly. Now its connecting to internet but unable to connect to many sites like yahoo, the pirate bay etc.

When I searched Google, I found that many people having Tenda router are facing similar problem but I couldn't find any solution. How can solve this problem?? Its the problem with router and not with me?

Comment: Are you able to resolve the domain to an IP address? Have you tried a different DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the MTU on your client machine to something low like 1380 and see if the problem goes away.

Some DSL ISPs require PPPoE, and PPPoE adds 8 bytes of overhead per packet, reducing your MTU by 8 bytes. Good home gateway routers that do PPPoE and NAT use a trick called "MSS clamping" to allow clients to stay set to their Ethernet-standard 1500-byte MTU without having problems. If your router isn't doing MSS clamping, it breaks your ability to send and receive full-size frames, which can make TCP connections (including HTTP connections) to most sites on the Internet fail on the first or second real application data packet.

Google is smart and always keeps their MTUs to something like 1380. It means efficiency and throughput take a small hit, but at least their site is reachable even from sites where the ISP or the gateway router is having MTU problems.

If you set your MTU down to 1380 and things start working, try some higher values and see if things still work. If 1492 works but 1493 doesn't, then it's probably a PPPoE-related problem, since PPPoE steals 8 bytes. If 1496 works but 1497 doesn't, it means your router is using VLAN tagging internally, but doesn't have correct hardware support for VLAN tagging. VLAN tags are 4 bytes long, and if your hardware doesn't support them correctly, those 4 bytes will be stolen from the MTU.